# Code Optimization Parsing Columns and Creating DateTime

Tags: python

The following code parses a text file, extracts column values, and creates a datetime column by combining a few of the columns.  What can I do to improve this code? More specifically, writing float(eq_params[1]), etc. was time-consuming.  Is there any way to more quickly parse the column data in Python, without using Pandas?  Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
file = 'input.txt'
fopen = open(file)
data = fopen.readlines()
fout = open('output.txt', 'w')
for line in data:
    eq_params = line.split()
    lat = float(eq_params[1])
    lon = float(eq_params[2])
    dep = float(eq_params[3])
    yr = int(eq_params[10])
    mo = int(eq_params[11])
    day = int(eq_params[12])
    hr = int(eq_params[13])
    minute = int(eq_params[14])
    sec = int(float(eq_params[15])) 
    dt = datetime.datetime(yr,mo,day)
    tm = datetime.time(hr,minute,sec)
    time = dt.combine(dt,tm)
    fout.write('%s %s %s %s\n'%(lat,lon,dep,time))
fout.close()
fopen.close()
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to convert from `str` to `float` and back to `str`.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the amount of typing by using a combination of `map`, slicing and variable unpacking to convert the parsed parameters and assign them in a single line:

```
lat, lon, dep = map(int, eq_params[1:4])
yr, mo, day, hr, minute, sec = map(float, eq_params[10:16])
```

using a list comprehension would work similarly:

```
lat, lon, dep = [int(x) for x in eq_params[1:4]]
```